# Pass Table name as Variable in sql query in Unix Shell Script Solaris

Tags: shell, unix, solaris

I'm creating a Unix shell script in solaris on which my task is to run the sql queries for 35 tables and bring the output to a csv file.For Which what I thought is that I will create an array of and by using for loop I will the pass the table name one by one to sql query.So as a sample I'm trying to pass the table name as variable in sql query.
I'm passing table name is sql query as well as the CSV which I m creating.
But is not working.Please help....

```
table_nm="PRODUCT"

sqlplus -s admin/admin_123@extend12 <<EOF 
SPOOL /data2/interfaces/scripts/`$table_nm`.CSV;
set colsep ,
set feedback off 
set trimspool on
set linesize 5000
set pagesize 1000
set heading on
set term off 
set verify off 
set timing off
set echo off
select * from `$table_nm` where PROD_ID = '1618' AND PROD_SER_NUM = 21 ;
spool off;
EXIT;
EOF
echo "end"
```

Comment: not back-quotes surrounding your variable, but dbl-quotes, ie. `SPOOL /data2/interfaces/scripts/"$table_nm".CSV;` . Hmm, or as you're inside a here-doc, you man not even need the dbl-quotes (or they may cause a problem. Stick with values for vars without spaces ;-! ).  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the array. Don't use back ticks.

```
tablearry=(PRODUCT SALES EMPLOYEES)


for i in "${tablearry[@]}"
 do
  table_nm=$i

sqlplus -s admin/admin_123@extend12 <<EOF 
SPOOL /data2/interfaces/scripts/${table_nm}.CSV;
set colsep ,
set feedback off 
set trimspool on
set linesize 5000
set pagesize 1000
set heading on
set term off 
set verify off 
set timing off
set echo off
select * from ${table_nm} where PROD_ID = '1618' AND PROD_SER_NUM = 21 ;
spool off;
EXIT;
EOF
echo "end"


done
```